# Expressing the completeness relation of an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Think of $\mathbb{C}^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, equipped with the Hermitian inner product.

Then, the standard basis $\{e_i\}$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$ satisfies the completeness relation as follows:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^\dagger e_i= I_{n}
\end{equation}
where $e_i$ is regarded as the column vector as $\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose. Also, $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

My question is that, does there exists an orthonormal basis $\{ \phi_i\}$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$ with respect to this Hermitian inner product that satisfies the completeness relation in the form
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n \phi_i^\dagger \phi_i= C\cdot I_{n}
\end{equation}
for any given nonzero constant $C$?

This seems like a tricky question for me..Could anyone help me?

Comment: Every orthonormal basis can be derived from the canonical one through a unitary transformation. It is thus easy to see that every orthonormal basis satisfy that condition with $C=1$

Comment: Oh...I see...thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a weird way of writing the completeness relation, in the sense that it is canonical to consider the elements of $\mathbb C^n$ as column vectors, and then the relation is then
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n e_ie_i^\dagger = I_{n}.
\end{equation}

This relation depends only on that the $\{e_i\}$ form an orthonormal basis; it is irrelevant that they are the canonical basis.

That is, if $\{\phi_i\}$ is orthonormal and $x\in\mathbb C^n$, we can write $x=\sum_jx_j\phi_j$ for appropriate coefficients $x_j$. Then
$$
\sum_i\phi_i\phi_i^\dagger\, x=\sum_i\sum_jx_j\phi_i\phi_i^\dagger\phi_j
=\sum_i\sum_jx_j\phi_i\,\delta_{i,j}=\sum_ix_i\phi_i=x.
$$
Thus
$$
\sum_i\phi_i\phi_i^\dagger=I_n. 
$$

Comment: Oh, I made a typo. Yes, your answer is what I originally meant.